# UML domain model visibility of fields

Tags: java, model-view-controller, uml

So I have seen this question: [In Java, difference between default, public, protected, and private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private) and decided to use `no modifier` in my domain model (MVC), but I cannot understand how do I put them in the domain model diagram?

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Visibility):

```
"+"       Public 
"-"       Private 
"#"       Protected 
"/"       Derived (can be combined with one of the others)
"_"       Static
```

But I do not see what shall I use for a field I do not put a modifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe '~' is the choice for default modifier.

> '~' : for package visibility

Here are the references:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/RationalEdge/sep04/bell/

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsdvhelp/v6r0m1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xtools.viz.java.doc%2Ftopics%2Fcvisibility.html

Comment: Do you have any source where you have seen that? I guess that is correct so I have accepted your answer, but I would like to read more as all the websites I have seen didn't mention that

Comment: @Nikola Added to the resolution